# Importing non-English shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile

I'm trying to import a shape-file like this:

```
fn <- "Proj1"
my_shp <- readShapeSpatial(fn)
```

On a windows-computer (32-bit) it works ok, but when I do the same from a Ubuntu-machine (64-bit, English OS, R2.14.0), I get "*Error in make.names(onames, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string 9*".

I suspect it is because the shapefile has Spanish origins, i.e. the names of polygons in it have accents like in "México" (not "Mexico").

As a quick fix, I did the import in windows, saved as .rda and loaded it in Ubuntu, but then I get for example "M\xfexico" as polygon name.

I'm not so experienced in Linux so I don't know if the fix is in R or in Ubuntu. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the encoding of your file. Maybe this [discussion at the R-br help list](http://r-br.2285057.n4.nabble.com/R-br-Erro-ao-importar-mapa-Shapefile-tp4023591p4024488.html) is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks! I read the email-chain and launched R from a terminal with "LC_ALL=C R", and that did it. Obrigado!

Comment: You should post an answer and checkmark it so it doesn't linger forever in the unanswered queue, Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to start R on the Ubuntu-computer by writing "LC_ALL=C R" in a terminal window. Thanks to Oscar Perpiñán for the solution.

Update: I use RStudio, where as far as I know it is not possible to start R with command-line parameters, but this works from inside RStudio:
    Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "C")

/Chris